# JavaScript Creating array in object and push data to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs, push

I'm new to programming. I'm trying React and have function addComment which is executed when a user adds a comment to news.I need to create in this moment a property **comments** (array) and assign or push to this array **inputCommentValue** value. But right now I only rewrite 0 element of the array and can't add a new element. 
Can you please tell me where to put push method? Thank you!

```
var ARTICLES = [{
  title: "sit amet erat",
  text: "nam dui proin leo odio porttitor id consequat in consequat ut nulla sed accumsan"

}, {
  title: "pulvinar sed",
  text: "velit id pretium iaculis diam erat fermentum justo nec condimentum"
}]



addComment(index, inputCommentValue){
ARTICLES = [...ARTICLES], ARTICLES[index].comments=[inputCommentValue];
this.setState({ARTICLES:ARTICLES});
}
```

Comment: this ARTICLES in your state?

Comment: Yes, ARTICLES is my state. It is updated properly. My problem is that I can't understand how to define (create) array and use method concat on it in the same time. I tried something like this:                                           `ARTICLES = [...ARTICLES], ARTICLES[index].comments=[].concat(inputCommentValue);`  But it works only for first element, next time (when user adds next comment) it rewrites array because of this `comments=[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that data exist in component's state , then handler will look something like that

```
addComment(index, inputCommentValue){
    // copy array , for not mutate state
    let ARTICLES = [...this.state.ARTICLES];
    // check if comments not exist
    if(!ARTICLES[index].comments) ARTICLES[index].comments=[];
    // add new comment to array
    ARTICLES[index].comments.push(inputCommentValue);
    // update component with new articles
    this.setState({ARTICLES:ARTICLES});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an object like this.

```
   foo : {
       bar : "x"
    }
```

To create an array, simply initialize it to an empty array.

```
foo.newArray = []
```

If you `console.log(foo)`, you will now see this

```
foo : {
   bar : "x",
   newArray : []
 }
```

This means your `foo` object has an empty array called `newArray`. You can add elements to it using the `push()` method.

Push a variable like this `foo.newArray.push(myVariable);`
Push a string like this `foo.newArray.push("myString");`
Push an object like this

```
 foo.newArray.push({
    "bar2" : "val2"
 });
```

For more information on arrays check [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

In your particular case, just do `ARTICLES.push({})`

Comment: Divyanth Jayaraj, thank you for this explanation! Now it is clearer for me!