# push property in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, properties, push

i want to push property in multidimensional array.
In this code i get TypeError: myArr.second[i].push is not a function...

```
var myArr = {
"main": 2000,
"second": [
{
  "step1": 10,
  "step2": "lorem ipsum",
  "step3": "bla, bla",
  },
  {
  "step1": 20,
  "step2": "TEXT, TEXT",
  "step3": "bla, bla, bla",
}]
};


for(i=0; i < myArr.second.length; i++){
  var toPush =  {};
  toPush["step4"] = "text";
  myArr["second"][i].push(toPush);
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: it's object so you can't use push method here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Creating array in object and push data to the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306219/javascript-creating-array-in-object-and-push-data-to-the-array)

Comment: The "second" is an array and you can use push here. But myArr is an Object, not an array. `myArr.second[0].step4 ="text"` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) or [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to define property.

```
for(i=0; i < myArr.second.length; i++){
  myArr["second"][i].step4 = "text";
}
```

---

Or you can use [`Object.assign`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=object%20assign) method to copy properties from another object.

```
for(i=0; i < myArr.second.length; i++){
  var toPush =  {};
  toPush["step4"] = "text";
  Object.assign(myArr["second"][i], toPush);
}
```

Comment: @user7206180 :  glad to help you :)